# How to build standalone php app with built-in http api gate?

Tags: php, microservices

I search for modern practice to build standalone php app with http support for some micro-service communications. Is there any solution like express or sames on nodejs to build server and some API ?  With nodejs it`s possible build many different services with each api built in http gates, I want try to do same on php.

I have watched standlone php server but it`s single threaded that`s is not good for production.

What`s is the better way ?

Answer (score 1):

Searhing in network get`s a result with two frameworks :

[ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/) and [AMPphp](https://amphp.org/)

These frameworks are suitable  for building standalone php apps. While non bloking, they also give some toolkit for http server and routing. Event driven model gives advantages also.